# Map function mess up results of a function in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, function, time

I am running a function I created in R called `getweather`, the function has three inputs:

`getweather(siteNumber,datatype,path_out)`

```
> dput(siteNumber)
c("GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023505")
> dput(datatype)
"PRCP"
> dput(path_out)
"C:/Users/Hydro/Precipitation/Data/Daily/"
```

The output of the function are two lists:

[image]

When I run the function using `Map` to avoid the function stops when there is an error, the output of the function (the two lists: List of 1 and List of 3) are merged or combined. This is the code:

```
Results = Map(function(x, y, z) tryCatch(getweather(x, y, z), error = function(e) message(paste("Error in Station", x))), x = siteNumber, y = datatype, z=path_out)
```

and the output using `Map` to run the function is(here the lists of the image above are combined):

[image]

How can I solve this problem? I want the output as the first image, but I think when using `Map` I mess up the two output lists.

I can provide the complete function in case it is needed.

Comment: Hi again. I would like to re-recommend writing your `get_weather` function in such a way that the `tryCatch` is present inside. Anyway, essentially you want to merge all the first elements together, and make a new list of the second elements, right? Try `new_list <- list() ; new_list[[1]] <- do.call("rbind", lapply(Results, \`[[\`, 1)) ; new_list[[2]] <- lapply(Results, \`[[\`, 2)`. Is `new_list` what you meant? Edit: Sorry, formatting messed up.

Answer (score 0):

What is going on is that

1. In the 1st iteration, `Map` is passing the 1st element of each of the input vectors to `getweather`:

   - `x = siteNumber[1]`;
   - `y = datatype[1]`;
   - `z = path_out[1]`;
2. In the 2nd iteration, `Map` is passing the 2nd element of each of the input vectors to `getweather` but th last two only have one element so R recycles them to the length of `siteNumber`:

   - `x = siteNumber[2]`;
   - `y = datatype[1]`;
   - `z = path_out[1]`;
3. etc.

In fact, the `Map` instruction is equivalent to the following `lapply` instruction.

```
Results <- lapply(siteNumber, function(x, y, z) {
  tryCatch(
    getweather(x, y, z), 
    error = function(e) message(paste("Error in Station", x))
  )}, 
  y = datatype,
  z = path_out
)
```

The solution is to post-process the returned list.

```
df_5_cols <- lapply(Results, '[[', 1)
df_6_cols <- lapply(Results, '[[', 2)

df_5_cols <- do.call(rbind, df_5_cols)
Results <- list(df_5_cols, df_6_cols)
```

Comment: I am using the lapply function that you suggest, but now I got a Large list where there is a list for each data frame. How can I unlist the dataframes inside of a list?

Comment: when I do the rbind inside the do.call I lost the names of the dataframes

Comment: @Sss Aren't those df's named `metadata`? Have you lost the 1st column, `Name`, or the row names?